# X-Men Origins: Why is Deadpool able to shoot lasers?

Tags: marvel, x-men

In X-Men Origins, Scott Summers lost his eyes, which were then put into Deadpool. After this event, in X-Men 1 through X-Men 3 Scott was still able to fire lasers, implying that the mutant ability was not related to the eyes? Yet Deadpool was able to fire the lasers with Scott's eyes. In addition Deadpool was able to control if he shot the beam, whereas Cyclops had to keep his eyes closed or adjust his visor.

Why is Deadpool able to shoot lasers with eyes and Cyclops without? Why is Deadpool able to control the lasers without the technology Cyclops has?

Comment: You fell victim to one of the classic blunders. The most famous is "Never get involved in a land war in Asia." But only slightly less well known is this: "Never try to apply logic to *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*."

Comment: @phantom42 comment of the year.

Comment: @XosMel This is pure speculation (hence comment and not answer), but if those doctors are advanced enough to combine and transplant mutant abilities, it's not too big of a stretch to imagine they might alter or improve them.  They simply improved on Cyclops's ability before adding it.  Also, maybe wait more than 44 minutes before declaring that "no one is replying."

Comment: @phantom42 -- great quote to give the actual insight :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Why is Deadpool able to shoot lasers with eyes and Cyclops without? Why is Deadpool able to control the lasers without the technology Cyclops has?

Because Cyclops origin story involves trauma (either mental psychological trauma, or actual head injury) that prevents him from controlling his powers. His brother Havok, who has similar enough powers as Scott that they can attack each other and it won't hurt, does not have this problem. This is why Scott needs Ruby-Quartz glasses or the visor to absorb the blasts which are always on.

> The early accounts in the X-Men comics use flashbacks to tell the origin story of Scott parachuting from his parents' plane. The flashbacks are often told from various narrative perspectives and place different emphasis on the events of this period. Scott's poor control over his power have been attributed to events in his childhood. In Uncanny X-Men #156, Scott's parachute caught fire and Scott struck his head upon landing. This caused brain damage to Scott which is responsible for his poor control over his optic blasts. Several origin stories do not feature the head injury account with X-Men Origins: Cyclops #1 being the most recent. The head injury account has also been retconned in Astonishing X-Men Vol. 2 as being due to a self-imposed mental block he made as a child to deal with the traumatic events of his life. With the help of Emma Frost, Scott is able to briefly bypass his own mental block and control his powers, though he reveals that his control is waning and temporary. [wikipedia]

As for Origins, you misunderstand what it is that happens in the movie, which is also pulled from the comics. Comic Deadpool is not a mutant, but his origins involve receiving a **COPY** of Wolverine's mutant healing factor. In the movie, this still happens. Notice that Wolverine was not deprived a healing factor, or his claws, yet Deadpool has both. He received copies of Wolverine's and Cyclops' powers  (along with Wraith's teleportation and Bradley's technopathy). This somehow involved surgery of the optic nerves. Scott at no point had his eyes removed. The bandages suggest a biopsy or surgery of the eyes that need to heal.

The reason Deadpool can use the optic blasts without the glasses is because he lacks the trauma that Scott received.

Answer (score -5):

the reason is because Hollyweird butt-pulled a bunch of powers for him because they didn't do any research before making the character in the film.  This is why Deadpool could shoot beams from his eyes, and had other powers he never had in the Marvel universe. They weren't doing any research and, at the time, had no plans to make a genuine Deadpool movie, so they deliberately fudged his powers, and they made him mute because the "Merc with a Mouth" wouldn't exactly be PG-13 friendly if he had any spoken lines.

They learned from this mistake, ultimately, and now we have a Deadpool who is not only true to form, but foul-mouthed and truly an Anti-hero.

Comment: Although this is largely true, OP was looking for an in-universe reason rather than a rant about how terrible the film was.

Comment: the problem is that there really is no "in-universe" reason that would justify the choices they made.  It's why it was critically panned by the comic-reading community in general.  So while it may make sense in a "Cinematic universe" perspective, it makes no sense to the overall origin of his powers, as in the comics, Cyclops had nothing to do with the creation of Deadpool.

Comment: Indeed. But that doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: Can you provide references for these claims?  For instance, have the writers mentioned this in interviews?

Comment: They quite obviously did do research, and made a concious decision to not follow the comics.